# How to structure Node.js project and respect DRY

Tags: javascript, node.js

This question may be flagged as **too broad**, nonetheless, I'll try.

I'm quite new to Node.js, I previously used it for specific minor tasks like intercepting data emitted by a raw socket and pass it forward via a web socket so I can have the data in the browser in real-time.

I've started a project at home with Node.js (as a learning experiment), and while writing code I often find myself repeating the same set of "instructions".

The end goal would be to have a pretty static site that would fetch data from a database so I don't have to commit whenever I want to correct a typo. The end result will have everything wrapped in a single request to the server, but for now, I separated pieces of data (mostly text) in models.

So, instead of having **company.model.js** and all the models looking like this

```js
let mongoose = require('mongoose');

let CompanySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    description: String
});
const Company = mongoose.model('Company', CompanySchema);

module.exports = Company;
```

I created a **BaseModel** that would perform common tasks, which looks like this.

```js
let mongoose = require('mongoose');

class BaseModel {
    constructor(name, schema, collection) {
        this.name = name;
        this.collection = collection ? collection : null;
        this.schema = new mongoose.Schema(schema);
    }

    build() {
        return mongoose.model(this.name, this.schema, this.collection);
    }
}

module.exports = BaseModel;
```

Now, **company.model.js** and other models will look like this.

```js
const BaseModel = require("@models/base/model");

module.exports = new BaseModel('company', {
    name: String,
    description: String
}).build();
```

Same thing about **services** and **controllers**.

**server/services/base/service.js**

```js
class BaseService {
    constructor(model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    fetchData() {
        let self = this;

        return async function (query) {
            try {
                return await self.model.find(query);
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e.message);
            }
        }
    }
}

module.exports = BaseService;
```

**server/services/company.service.js**

```js
let Company = require('@models/company.model');
let BaseService = require('@services/base/service');

let CompanyService = new BaseService(Company);
exports.fetchData = CompanyService.fetchData();
```

**server/controllers/base/controller.js**

```js
class BaseController {
    constructor(service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    getEntries(query) {
        let self = this;

        return async function (req, res) {
            try {
                let data = await self.service.fetchData(query);
                return res.status(200).json({
                    data: data
                });
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e.message);
            }
        }
    }
}

module.exports = BaseController;
```

**server/controllers/company.controller.js**

```js
let CompanyService = require("@services/company.service");
let BaseController = require("@controllers/base/controller");

exports.getCompanies = new BaseController(CompanyService).getEntries({
    description: "whatever"
});
```

Now all of this works and I got a functional "API", ready to be *devoured* by Angular, but I'm not sure whether the approach I took was okay or not.

Things don't seem that standardized in Node.js and Express, all the posts I've read on how to actually structure an app using this server stack were contradictory.

How do you structure your Node.js/Express project? How do you make it in such way that you don't have to repeat code?

Resources/plain links/boilerplate repos are welcome.

Comment: after reading this post https://www.terlici.com/2014/08/25/best-practices-express-structure.html  I've came to my own idea with ~ near to that example

Comment: Thanks, that's close to what I need, except the view part cause I don't want any view engine, I got Angular for that. I think Express is used solely for routing and response preparations in my case. They should come up with a default file/folder structure (as guideline, not enforced) cause it'll be easier for new people to adapt (coming from PHP, Ruby etc.), saving time and making sure people at least understand best practices before choosing to go wild and free in terms project structure & architecture.

Comment: of course, I'm not fan of rendering views from serverside. I'm using angular for it. For generation of boilerplate there's `express-generator` https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html , but models, db tools are extra that developer must choose him/herself - cause express is not MVC framework.

Comment: btw previously I had such minimal (primitive) approach: https://github.com/num8er/alttab-nodejs-challenge